# How to use D-Link card Air Plus G DWL-G510 with Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless

I have D-Link card Air Plus G DWL-G510. It is not working now with ubuntu. Is other way to install somthing for this card?

If not which Wi-Fi card you recommended for Ubuntu for PC not laptop?

P/N EWLG510EU.C2G
H/W Ver.:C2 F/W Ver.:5.11

Answers for yours questions:

1.
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list

```
0f:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT2561/RT61 rev B 802.11g [1814:0302]
    Subsystem: D-Link System Inc AirPlus G DWL-G510 Wireless Network Adapter (Rev.C) [1186:3c09]
    Kernel driver in use: rt61pci
    Kernel modules: rt61pci
3f:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5761 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1681] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company NetXtreme BCM5761 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [103c:3047]
    Kernel driver in use: tg3
    Kernel modules: tg3
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

2. More informations about which version of Ubuntu:

   Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

dmesg | grep rt61pciv :

```
[   28.579064] rt61pci 0000:0f:00.0 wls4: renamed from wlan0
```

Comment: Hardware recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: what that mean? I cant use my PC with ubuntu. No internet connection. Where should I ask if askubuntu is wrong place?

Comment: Please edit to add more information about which version of Ubuntu you are using. Also post the output of the command `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`

Comment: @Pilot6 I have edited the question to make it on topic.

Comment: I edited my post and pasted there answare for lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list and ubuntu version

Comment: `RT61` is an unlucky chip. But it is "supported". What does `dmesg | grep rt61pci` show?

Comment: I added answare for  dmesg | grep rt61pci

Comment: Linux Hardware says that in some computers running Ubuntu 20.04, it is just detected, and in some computers, it "works". https://linux-hardware.org/?id=pci:1814-0302-1186-3c09

Comment: Can you install the latest kernel with `sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-18.04-edge` and reboot to check if it works?

Comment: it looks like it works.

Comment: Right now i am using internet connection via usb tethering from my phone. I am executing sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-18.04-edge. Next I will rebot.

Comment: Yes it look like it is working but not completely. I can see connection to network.  But usually it say: No internet connection when i open mozilla, when I see that i am connected to wifi network.

Comment: Now I am after rebot. I selected my network. Next i wrote my password. Next my network was not wisible for me and I can see info that i am not connected to network. Close to my PC is my laptop right now and there is working.

Comment: I can buy something but you have to tell me what.  Is my country inportant for you? If you can not get public information, please send me a prv message.